# Checking for duplicate values in a column

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Input
3 A 4 4.2
4 B 5 3.2
5 C 4 4.0
5 D 4 8.0
........
```

The only columns of interest are 0,1 and 3. My script below does the following: if value in column 1 matches a particular letter, column 3 is multiplied by a constant. 
I now want to go through column 0 and if there are repeating integers, add the values in column 3 together (ie. there are two 5's in column 0 so, I would add 1.2 and 2.4 (values after multiplication with constant, 4.0 x 0.3 = 1.2)).

```
Output
3 A 4 3.4
4 B 5 3.2
5 C 4 3.6 (the entries in column 1 and 2 don't really matter after addition)
........
```

I think this would be easy in pandas but I've written in some dictionaries so that complicates the process:

```
import numpy as np

ring_dict = dict()
answer = []
ring = open('data.txt', "r")

for line in ring:
     f2 = line.split(" ")
     key2 = int(f2[0])
     value2 = float(f2[3])
     name = f2[1]
     ring_dict[key2] = [name, value2]
         if name == 'A':
             answer = value2 * 0.81
         elif name == 'B':
             answer = value2 * 1
         else:
             answer = value2 * 0.3
```

I'm not sure how to proceed here. I can't iterate through key2 (ie. for x in key2) to find repeats - so I'm not sure how to check for duplicates. Likewise if I make key2 into an array, the dictionary doesn't work.

Comment: If the first index is a duplicate, do you add all the duplicate `value2` together before applying a constant? What are you doing with `answer`? In your example you just keep reassigning it.  Did you mean to append the calculated `value2` into a `list` of `answer`? What happens with `answer` when there are duplicates?

Comment: @Idlehands - yes, the input shows the `value2` already multiplied by the constants. The script I wrote above works to multiply `value2` by the specified constant and then saves the answers to an array (answer=[]).

Comment: If you're input is already multiplied by the constants, why are you multiplying them again in your code after reading it? It's a bit confusing because in the output it seems the only thing you want to achieve is just combine duplicate rows together.

Comment: @Idlehands - sorry, I was trying to simplify it by only changing one variable in the example - the multiplication part works, I'm having trouble with summing the  `answer[i]` for the duplicate key2s.

Comment: Okay, bear with me here.  In your example, 1.) are the `1.2` and `2.4` in the last two row *after* multiplication? 2.) Assuming it is, are the sums cumulative? i.e. is `answer` supposed to read `[3.4, 3.2, 1.2, 3.6...]`? 3.) do answer need to match any key? Because in this case after `answer[2]` it'll be a mismatch against the `dict` you've created.  4.) I also don't understand the purpose of the `dict`, is it supposed to interact with `answer` afterwards?

Comment: @Idlehands - I guess I really screwed up explaining this one. I edited the question to try and answer some of your questions. My thinking was that I would create another dictionary with the answers, but I didn't know how that would account for the duplicate keys (I didn't want to do a nested dictionary). Furthermore, I have other attributes that I want to assign to these keys later on and thought that creating a dictionary would be the way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want (especially with column 1 and 2), but as you mentioned, with `pandas` the problem becomes a bit more trivial:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the csv into a pd.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None)

# Multiply the column[3] by the given constant (default to 0.3 if not 'A' or 'B')
df[3] = df.apply(lambda x: round(x[3] * {'A': 0.81, 'B': 1}.get(x[1], 0.3),1), axis=1)

# Group the DataFrame by column[0] and return a new DataFrame with the sum; drop column[2].
df = df.groupby(0).agg(['sum']).drop(columns=2).reset_index(col_level=0)

# Drop the multi-index returned by the agg() method
df.columns = newdf.columns.droplevel(1)

#    0   1    3
# 0  3   A  3.4
# 1  4   B  3.2
# 2  5  CD  3.6
```

This allow you more freedom to manipulate the data.  But if you still need it in a `dict` format like yours, you can do this:

```
my_dict = {v[0]: [v[1],v[2]] for v in newdf.to_dict('list').values()}

# {3: [4, 5], 'A': ['B', 'CD'], 3.4: [3.2, 3.5999999999999996]}

# Note: rounding issue on the last part, but that's easier to smooth out.
```

I'll update this answer with a `dict` variant if still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `ring_dict[key2[i]]` exists and either initialize or increment it using the following

```
for i in range(len(f2)):
    if(not ring_dict[key2[i]]):
        ring_dict[key2[i]]=[name[i],value2[i]]
    else:
        ring_dict[key2[i]][1]+=value2[i]
```

Comment: You probably want `ring_dict.get(key2)` instead.  It'll return `None` if not found instead of a `KeyError`